# Simple API Access status: suddenly INACTIVE

Tags: google-drive-api

I was developing android application that has backup to google drive feature.
I have used Simple API Access key and it worked like a charm for few weeks.

However, from yesterday, it does not work at all. (cannot list uploaded files and 403 fobidden error when trying to upload new file) I checked Google APIs Console and found out

Simple API Access 
Status: Inactive

and Reports is not available and keeps showing popup message "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it."

I googled about this message but there is no solution. (but found several issues related to google cloud SQL)
I was considering to use google drive on commercial level android app and this is very bad...
I wonder what is the problem and how to reactivate api status.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, because of the security model of the Drive SDK, we need to be sure that an application is who they say they are, which simple access does not give enough assurance of. For a commercial application, this strength of security is great for users.

For a solution, you need to use Google Play Services as [outlined in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui). We are currently working on a guide to get started with this very quickly on Android, and should be available within the next week.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that simple api access does not give high strength security for users. I am not sure what is going to be added to Integrate with the Android Drive App section but still many android user does not have Drive app and I guess there will be many limitation that third party app can do with google drive. I liked the way I have done. Will google deprecate accessing google drive with simple api access? if it will not happen I would like to stick this way and want to solve inactive problem

Comment: By the way the new restriction we just put in place should not affect you if you were using the full Drive scope but only if you were using the drive.file scope. Nevertheless you should use the Play services to authorize as it is better in any case.

Comment: I guess google drive team did something to restrict drive.file scope. I was using drive.file scope.. It is kind of confusing that the link Ali Afshar provided was about "Integrate with the Android Drive App" and it only describes "open with" function on google drive app. But I need to upload file and do not want to use external intent + activity (google drive app) flow. At the same time, both of you talks about Google Play service.... I will try to solve this problem with full scope ... and see what you guys are preparing..

Comment: Changed google drive api scope from "drive.file" to "drive" and it works very well. Howver,  in the Google APIs Console, status of Simple API Access is still InActive and "Reports" is unavailable ( "An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it." pop up) Thanks Nivco and I will look forward to more google drive documentation for Android next week :)